# view in a subfolder

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

When i define my controller,model and view in 'application.js' i get automatic getter.

```
Directory '/app/view/' view 'client.js'

I get a getter getClientView().
```

But if i put that in a subfolder like '/app/view/operation/', i get de getter too?

How can i access?

```
Ext.define('ImpPdf.Application', {
name: 'ImpPdf',

extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
views: [
    'operation.Client'
],
controllers: [
],
stores: [
]
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you get a getter too. Look at the Google dev tool. It's autocompletion feature comes in handy for this question.

```
getOperationClientView()
```

Or

```
getView('operation.Client')
```

Personnally I prefer the latter.